# Name NSUserDefaults Automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, webview, tableview

Please excuse me, because this is a little hard to explain. I'll try my best!

So, I'm creating bookmarks. I've gotten as far as bringing the URL of the WebView to the table where you are able to set it and display it. That works well for one bookmark. Here's what the code looks like:

```
//Gets Page (currentAddress is the address of the webview passed to the bookmarks)
NSString *address = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentAddress"];

//Adds Set URL To Defaults (defaults is the name for the NSUserDefaults declaration)
[defaults setObject:address forKey:@"savedAddress1"];

//Adds To Array (favorites is the mutable array that the table displays)
[favorites addObject:address];

//Syncs Defaults
[defaults synchronize];

//Animate Back To Home Screen
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, when you add new bookmarks, they just overwrite eachother. How are you able to name them consecutively so that they don't just write over eachother automatically? Keep in mind that I need to know how to get the index for deletion and also check if it's nil.

So, please, if you have anything that would help me in this situation it would be great. I was thinking perhaps using an array in the NSUserDefaults to keep track, but again, I don't know and I need your help!

Thanks For Your Time!

--Jake

Comment: An `NSArray` is fine to stick in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Great! Just.. how would you go about naming each part of the array automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data structure gets too complicated you should consider another method of storage.

You could probably get away with using an `NSDictionary` with the Key being the name of the bookmark and the value being the bookmark address.

```
{
    "Google" = "http://google.com"
}
```

When you load your data source you should to grab the dictionary from `NSUserDefaults`

```
self.bookmarks = [[userDefaults dictionaryForKey:URDictionaryKey] mutableCopy];
```

To keep your table in order you could create an `NSArray` of the dictionaries keys that is sorted.

```
self.bookmarkKeys = [[self.bookmarks allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

For your datasource methods you use something like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [self.bookmarkKeys count];
}
```

For the cell configuration you use something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSString *title = [self.bookmarkKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text       = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.bookmarks objectForKey:title];

    return cell;
}
```

If a user deletes a row in the table, you would do something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSString *key = [self.bookmarkKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.bookmarks removeObjectForKey:key];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:self.bookmarks forKey:URDictionaryKey];
        [defaults synchronize];

    }
}
```

---

Update

You would need to use an [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it's a subclass of [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) so looking at the docs for both would help your understanding.

In this case you would start with an empty mutable dictionary

```
self.bookmarks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Then when a user adds a bookmark you add it to the dictionary using the name as the `key` and the destination as the `value`

```
[self.bookmarks setObject:@"http://google.com" forKey:@"Google"];
```

Comment: Believe me, as a bit of a beginner (I've been using XCode for about 2 months), this is going to be tough. I've never used an NSDictionary before. The rest of your answer seems simple enough, but how do you go about setting up the NSDictionary? Thanks! =D

Comment: I've gone with an intricate system of booleans. It checks if the entry is nil, and if it is it adds the bookmark there. The only problem I'm having is deleting them.. how do you tell which row is being deleted so that I can set the NSDefault for that row to nil?

Comment: The `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` gives you the indexPath. It's hard to imagine your setup without seeing some code so I can't really help too much

Comment: I put this together, finally, 1000 times more simple. I just add an entire array to NSUserDefaults, then load that array into the array the table displays when it loads, and when you change the array the table displays, it saves back over the array in the defaults.